# Setting up QEMU and MIPSEL : networking trouble

Tags: networking, qemu

I have a MIPSEL machine running on QEMU. In order to enable networking inside my qemu MIPSEL machine, I use a bridge `virbr0`.

First, I create the interface tap0 and bring it up. I do it as follows :-

> sudo tunctl -t tap0 && sudo ifconfig tap0 up`

Next, I add `tap0` and the interface that brings in the internet connection(in this case `eth1`) to the bridge.

> sudo brctl addif virbr0 tap0
>
> sudo brctl addif virbr0 eth1

Finally, I start off my QEMU machine with the flags `-net nic -net tap,ifname=tap0,script=no,downscript=no`.

At this point a couple of things happen.

1. I am not able to access the internet connection from my QEMU MIPS machine. It seems to be able to ping `virbr0` and `eth1`'s ip address, however, it is unable to reach the internet.
2. The second I add the `eth1` interface to `virbr0` my host loses its ability to connect to the internet. It is able to connect to the internet only if I remove `eth1` from `virbr0`.

How can I solve [1] and/or [2]?

Thanks!

Comment: What does the routing table look like? Did you try to ping the outside world by name or by IP?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496449/networking-is-not-working-on-qemu-guest-malta-mips

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number 2, if you have a physical interface on a bridge, the bridge should be the thing that has the IP address, not the physical interface.  I suspect your eth1 still has the address.  Try assigning the IP to `virbr0` instead.  So, do an `ip addr del` from `eth1` and then `ip addr add` with the same IP/netmask to `virbr0`.  Also, use `ip route show` to make sure the default route is not going to try to go out `eth1` as well.  Note, that `eth1` still needs to be up, it just should not have an IP address.

I suspect that will also help clear up number 1, assuming your VM is getting a suitable IP for reaching the network.

Comment: This is great thanks! Now I get the internet from within the QEMU image but I don't seem to from the host machine(the eth1 interface does not have an ip address of its own at this point). Is that the intended result?

Comment: @uki you should be able to get network access back for the host itself by adding the IP information that had previously been on eth1 to the bridge itself.  Ultimately `eth1` will still be used for traffic, but it will never need to explicitly have an address of its own